Logistic regression on unknown features
Consider the following problem: I want to classify data into classes. The features have names, and for example, assume that the names are lowercase words in english. We assume that not all elements of the dataset have a value for each feature: for example, if we assume that each element of the dataset is a sentence $s$, and that each feature's (corresponding to a word $w$) value is the number of times word $w$ appears in $s$, then of course, for some word $w$ and some sentence $s$, the feature whose name is $w$ for sentence $s$ may be undefined, just because the word-counting algorithm does not include the $0$'s for each non-occurring word.
Let's also say that I'm using Python, sklearn and LogisticRegression.
How to deal with this situation in an automatic fashion? It would be possible to, for each sentence $s$ in the dataset, add a $0$ for each non-appearing word $w$, but this would make the data huge, if we assume that most sentences only contain a very, very small fraction of words. Moreover, hypothetical new data may use new words that have never been seen before, so this approach may not even be possible. Is there a way to tell Python, or sklearn, to just consider, during its training, that whenever it sees a piece of data that contains a feature that the training had never seen before, to just initialize all corresponding weights at this time, making as if this feature had actually seen to be $0$ for all previous data pieces?
From a completely abstract linear-algebraic point of view, all of this is pretty trivial: missing values or zeroes can unambiguously be considered as the same thing, and in terms of matrices, it's just about considering some matrices as submatrices of some other ones. But how to do it in practice?

Sounds very generic. Are you trying to work with tabular data, or is it about finding embeddings for sentences? Example of incoming data might help.
